# Restricting calls from socket program to servlet

Tags: sockets, servlets

How do I restrict calls from a socket program invoking my servlet ?

Thanks,
rudran

Answer (score 0):

Every request to the sever comes through socket only. Even the browser send the requests using a socket.

But if your requirement is to allow only certain User-Agents access your servlets. Write a filter which allows only certain User-Agents to allow accessing.

Normally request from Java client comes with user agent `Java/1.6.0_23-ea`. You can filter such clients.

And requests from browser will have like this `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-GB; rv:1.9.2.17) Gecko/20110420 Firefox/3.6.17`.

To know more about User-Agents, please refer following links

1. [List of User Agents](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php)
2. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent)